# How can I display the number of seconds until an NSTimer next fires

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstimer

I have a simple OSX Menubar application, the status item has a menu attached to it and I have a menu item that can manually send a `fire` to a NSTimer.

I'd like for that menu item to display the number of seconds until the next time the timer will be fired. Is there a way to get the amount of time until the next fire or the time at which the NSTimer will be next fired?

Comment: It's math, just sub 1 from total timer time each second

Comment: You won't be able to keep the display up-to-date without a second timer...

Comment: @JoshCaswell this may be splitting peas, but yes that’s perfectly possible, as long as the timer repeats.

Comment: @danyowdee: Uh, well, sure, but only at the interval that the timer's firing at, so either the timer's firing so often that the display's going to read "1 sec left" all the time, or it'll say "5 min left" for the entire five-minute period.

Comment: @JoshCaswell oh you’re right: it doesn’t make a lot of sense to refer to the date some timer is going to fire, if one wants an updating display of time remaining until some event…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSTimer has fireDate wich returns a NSDate. NSDate has timeIntervalSinceNow.

Answer (score 2):

I know there’s already an accepted answer, but it just occurred to me, that you actually may not be interested in the `fireDate`, at all:

Using that date, you’ll only see the same number of seconds, for as long as the time is displayed — if it’s displayed directly in the menu bar, there is no indication of progress…

I’d therefor suggest a slightly different approach:

1. Calculate, and store the expiry date.
2. Schedule a repeating timer, that fires at an interval matching your displayed precision, and updates the remaining time display, using the stored expiry date.
3. As soon, as you’ve passed the expiry date, invalidate the timer, and do whatever it is you want to do, then.

#### So, why not use a one second timer, and a decrementing counter variable, then?

Simple: `NSTimer` is not a real-time thing. The actual date a timer fires, and its scheduled `fireDate` will be slightly different. But since repeating timers re-schedule without adjusting for that difference, these deviations add up.

These deviations are completely unpredictable, as they depend not only on the load of your App, but the system as a whole. So they will vary between “completely neglible”, and “ZOMFG”!

Comment: Thanks for the useful additional info.